# Prove by tableau method - Axioms of equality

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Example:**

Let $T^*$ be a theory with axioms of equality. Prove by tableau method that

(a) $T^* \vDash x=y \rightarrow y=x \qquad $  (symmetry of =)

(b) $T^* \vDash (x=y \, \land \,y=z) \rightarrow x=z \qquad$ (transitivity of =)

**Hint:** To show (a) apply the axiom of equality (iii) for $x_1=x,\; x_2=x,\; y_1=y,\;  y_2=x$, to show (b) apply (iii) for $x_1=x,\; x_2=y,\; y_1=z$

(a) Should the root of the tableau looks like this?

[image]

Then I use substitution and I get $F(y_1=x_1) -T(y_1=x_1)-\circ$

Then it is proved right?

Comment: Taky vás Gregor takhle trápil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use both *equality axioms* :

> $\forall x \ (x=x)$ --- *reflexivity*
>
> $\forall x \ \forall y \ (x=y) \to (\phi \to \phi')$ --- where $\phi'$ is obtained from $\phi$ by replacing $x$ in zero or more places by $y$ : *replacement axiom*.

Specifically, the instance of the *replacement axiom* needed is :

> > $\forall x \ \forall y \ ((x=y) \to [ (x=x) \to (y=x)])$.

---

The tableau must start with the axioms and the negation of the conclusion :

> $\text F \ [ \ \forall x \ \forall y \ ((x=y) \to (y=x)) ]$.

Thus, you have first to "unpack" the leading quantifiers, correctly using $y_1$ and $x_1$ new, to get:

> $\text F \ ((x_1=y_1) \to (y_1=x_1))$

and then :

> $\text T \ (x_1=y_1)$
>
> $\text F \ (y_1=x_1)$.

But this does not close.

---

1) $\text T \ \forall x \ (x=x)$ --- axiom

2) $\text T \ \forall x \ \forall y \ ((x=y) \to [ (x=x) \to (y=x)])$ --- axiom

3) $\text F \ \forall x \ \forall y \ ((x=y) \to (y=x))$ - negation of conclusion

4) $\text T \ (x_1=y_1)$ --- from 3)

5) $\text F \ (y_1=x_1)$ --- from 3)

6) $\text T \ (x_1=x_1)$ --- from 1)

7) $\text T \ ((x_1=y_1) \to [ (x_1=x_1) \to (y_1=x_1)])$ --- from 2).

Left branch:

8)  $\text F \ (x_1=y_1)$ --- closes with 4).

Right branch :

9) $\text T \ ((x_1=x_1) \to (y_1=x_1))$.

Left branch :

10) $\text F \ (x_1=x_1)$ --- closes with 6).

Right branch :

11) $\text T \ (y_1=x_1)$ --- closes with 5).